# How can I represent a graph problem in PDDL?

Tags: pddl

For example I have the following problem: I have a salesman agent that sells 4 products (a, b, c, and d). it has 10 costumers overall: 3 that need product a, 3 that need product b, 3 that need product c, and 1 that needs product d. not every client has a road (link) to all other clients. the agent is currently at the home of costumer 1 that needs product a and his goal is to get satisfy costumer 10 who needs product d. such that it needs to go through all the clients to get to costumer 10.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your graph as a set of 'connectivity predicates' in the `init` section, eg:

```
(adjacent l1 l2) (adjacent l2 l3) ...
```

This represents a connection between `l1` and `l2` and between `l2` and `l3`; those could be waypoints or the locations of your customers. You then need an action that moves along the graph:

```
(:action move
     :parameters (?from ?to - location)
     :precondition (and
             (adjacent ?from ?to)
             (at salesman ?from))
     :effect (and
             (at salesman ?to)
             (not (at salesman ?from)))
```

You then also need an action `deliver` that makes sure the salesman has some goods, is at a customer, and as an effect the customer has the goods (and the salesman doesn't). Then you set as the `goal` that all customers have the goods they want, and you should be good to go.